# 3 Dimensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

I am implementing a 3 dimensional array.  Much like cells and sheets of an Excel document.  x and y being the page size and z being the number of sheets.  For now the x and y indices can be the same for every page.

I thought to approach this with vectors (let's for now just say for strings only), but declaring it as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> sheets;
//x and y being the x-y coordinates and z being the number of pages.
int size = x*y*z;
sheets.reserve(size);
```

Thus giving me a nice contiguous piece of memory (as is definition of a std::vector), which is fast and efficient.

My question is:  Is there a way of doing this with std::array?
Is there a way that to create the array size when the object is created, or must this be know at compile time?

```
class sheetsObj
{
    int x, y, z;
    int size;
    //Where size is x * y * z.
    std::array<std::string, size> sheets;
public:
   sheetsObj(int xInd, int yInd, int zInd) : x{ xInd }, y{ yInd }, z{ zInd } {};
   ....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For `std::array` the size must be known at compile time. Why do you want to use `std::array` anyway? I would suspect `x*y*z` might get a bit large for the stack.

Comment: `std::array` requires the size to be known at compile time. You can use a `template` to specify the size, if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best rule of thumb is to use `std::vector` when you can, `std::array` when you have to. In this case, `std::vector` is the best option for you. As you say, the size of `std::array` must be known at compile-time, so this is a no-brainer if you need dynamically-sized storage.

Comment: Hum, I thought it was the other way around: use `std::array` when you can (i.e. when you know the size at compile time) else use `std::vector`. Can you elobrate on this rule of thumb of yours?

Comment: Sure, std::vector is a more flexible data type which is easier to react to changing requirements with. It will generally make programming an easier task, which is always desirable. Using std::array is good when working in an environment where heap-allocation is expensive or you have profiled your code and found that the `vector`s are causing an issue. Otherwise it is generally a premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` has its size fixed by a template parameter, thus evaluated at compile time and probably not suitable for your needs (unless all the sheets are designed to have the same size forever?).

A `std::vector` will perfectly meet your requirements, since the resizing overhead is not used by your program, and you will get your memory block as needed.

`std::dynarray` would probably be the best class for you to use, since it represents a runtime initializable array which remains fixed-sized during his lifetime. However, initially scheduled to be released with the C++14 standard, a vote has been cast to exclude it from the upcoming standard, leaving it to be proposed later into a separate Technical Specification.